# File_get_contents not returning Json data from url

Tags: php, json

I've checked the php ini file and the function is clearly enabled. The Json data itself is 100% valid too, so I'm really stumped on this one. Should be a simple task! I'm trying to do this in a localhost (Xamp) environment which I'm not too familiar with so maybe that is affecting the result? Any help appreciated.Have a look at the url if you like.

```
$json_url = "http://api.vatlookup.eu/rates/be/";
$json = file_get_contents($json_url);
$data = json_decode($json, TRUE);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Your code is working properly.

Answer (score 0):

> This is likely related to the ini configuration setting [`allow_url_fopen`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen).

Your code should work, it works in my environment.

You can test it from command line by running:

`php.exe -r "echo file_get_contents('http://api.vatlookup.eu/rates/be/');"`

Returns this
JSON:

```
{
    "rates": [
        {
            "name": "Super Reduced",
            "rates": []
        },
        {
            "name": "Reduced",
            "rates": [
                6,
                12
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Standard",
            "rates": [
                21
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Increased",
            "rates": []
        },
        {
            "name": "Parking",
            "rates": [
                12
            ]
        }
    ],
    "disclaimer": "Rates data is based on information published by the European Commission, updated 1st January 2017."
}
```

Sometimes you need to set the user-agent and referer. I am providing an alternative using cURL in hopes that it might be of use to you:

```
function get_data() {
    $ch = curl_init("http://api.vatlookup.eu/rates/be/");
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
        'Referer: http://api.vatlookup.eu/rates/be/',
        'User-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3095.5 Safari/537.36'
    ]);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}
```

Example Usage:

```
$data = get_data();
$json = json_decode($data, true);
echo "<pre>",print_r($json,true),"</pre>";
```